# Variable not working in mail form?

Tags: php, forms, email, variables

I have a HTML form with 4 id (name, email, message, subject), a js with all the variables declared and a PHP that should send the mail.

HTML

```
            <form id="formail" method="post" action="">
                <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"  value="" size="22" /><br />
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email"  value="" size="54" /><br />
                <textarea id="messaggio" name="messaggio" rows="1" cols="55" style="resize: none;"></textarea><br />
                <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"  value="" size="22" /><br />
                <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="" style="cursor: pointer"/>
                <br />
                <div id="answer"></div>
            </form>
```

This is the js

```
    var valid = '';
    var isr = ' requested.</h6>';
    var name = $("#nome").val();
    var mail = $("#email").val();
    var subject = $("#subject").val();
    var messaggio = $("#messaggio").val();
```

(follow controls about the name and mail, and the send function)

This is the php

```
    $mail = trim($_POST['mail']);
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $text = $_POST['messaggio'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $to = "admin@test.com";

    $message = "Username: ".$name.", ".$mail.".<br />";
    $message .= "Subject: ".$subject.".<br />";
    $message .= "Messaggio: <br />".$text."<br /><br />";
    $message .= "IP: ".$ip."<br />";
    $headers = "From: ".$mail." \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$mail." \r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 \n";

     if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        echo "<h6>Message sent!</h6>";
      }
```

I posted only the relevant code. When I click send I'll receive the mail, however the field "subject" is blank, as if the variables "subject" had been ignored.

Could you please help me? I'm starting to learn PHP but I'm still a newbie. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the HTML.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and see what your form is really sending. Since you're using JS to build form submission variables (looks like, anyways), you've probably got a typo somewhere along the line.

Comment: I think you should try PHPMailer, it's very good with sending e-mails with a lot of options.

Comment: @ToddMurray HTML added.
SzamDev Thank you but I am trying to do everything by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your mail function?

use following mail function:

```
mail($to-mail,$subject,$message,$header);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I was already using that function, only not mentioned in my post. I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Two key points here:

a) Not sure exactly what function you're using to actually send the mail, but assuming PHP mail() you will need to use the $subject as the second parameter.

b) If you publish this on the open web you will be exploited as an open relay by spammers.

The attack you are vulnerable to is called 'header injection'.
In short, if I submit my 'mail' value as `myemail@example.org%0ABcc:poorsap@example.com` the script will add an extra line (the `%0A` is a linefeed), and submit to mail() with an extra Bcc header for however many emails I like (in this case `poorsap@example.org`).

Please take a read through this: http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection and consider using an alternate library to avoid this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am not planning to use it on public networks, only trying to get it working locally. 

I'll consider an alternate library for public purposes in future!